# Trustpas.com does detect somehow your identity

Tags: anonymity

I am not a programmer or an IT insider, 
I tested your browser by creating different accounts and then publishing reviews for a same company, however, Trustpilot instantly flagged my reviews because they saw something identical to the other review. I am following all the rules on deleting cookies etc, but someway I can not truely browse anomously because Trustpas.com for instance instantly found out.
Dave

Comment: check for persistent cookies like [Evercookie](https://github.com/samyk/evercookie)

Comment: correct, I have been working on this and in the meanwhile I learnt an aweful lot, check on https://www.browserleaks.com/ what they can put on your computer in order to identify you!!

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you did your testing all in one session. As far as I understand, tor randomly assigns an exit node when you start the browser but keeps you locked onto that node as long as it is kept alive so if you left the browser running for a  few days as you experimented I wonder if Trustpas simply recognized the ip of the exit node and attached the test reviews to that ip?